# Mujica's "Complex analysis in Banach spaces" exercise 1.A.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, polynomials, banach-spaces

I'm trying to prove Exercise 1.A. in Mujica's book "Complex analysis in Banach spaces" which states the following:

> Let $A \in L_a(^m E;F)$ be an $m$-linear mapping which is separately continuous in each variable. Using the Principle of Uniform Boundedness show that A is continuous.

Where $E,F$ are Banach spaces and $L_a(^mE;F)$ is the vector space of all mappings $A:E^m\rightarrow F$.

I dont know how to prove it. If anyone show me that, i would be grateful.

Comment: Did you attempt the case $m=2$?

Comment: I think this can be a hint: For fixed elements $e_1,\dots,e_{m-1} \in E$, $x\mapsto A(e_1,\dots, e_{m-1}, x)$ is a linear map $E\to F$.

Answer (score 1):

For all $x_2,...,x_n$ there are constants $C(x_2,...,x_n)$ so that

$$\sup_{x_1\in B_1(0)}\|A(x_1,...,x_n)\|≤ C(x_2,...,x_n).$$

This follows since $A$ is separately continuous in every variable (here $B_1(0)$ denotes unit ball of $E$). Now let $k<n$ and suppose by induction that for all $x_k,....,x_n$ there are constants $C(x_k,...,x_n)$ so that
$$\sup_{x_1,...,x_{k-1}\in B_1(0)}\|A(x_1,...,x_n)\|≤ C(x_k,...,x_n),$$
ie that $A$ is jointly continuous in the first $k-1$ variables. You may rewrite this as:

$$\sup\{\|A(x_1,...,x_{k-1}, x_k, x_{k+1},...,x_n)\|\mid x_1,..,x_{k-1}\in B_1(0)\}<\infty$$

And then uniform boundednes yields common bound on the norms of hte linear maps:
$$\{y\mapsto A(x_1,...,x_{k-1},y,x_{k+1},...,x_n) \mid x_1,...,x_{k-1}\in B_1(0)\}.$$
In other words:
$$C(x_{k+1},...,x_n):=\sup_{x_k\in B_1(0)}\quad \sup_{x_1,...,x_{k-1}\in B_1(0)}\|A(x_1,...,x_n)\|<\infty$$
for any $x_{k+1},...,x_{n}$. This completes the induction step.